# Fast file synchronization tool with a web GUI for Linux?

Tags: linux, web-apps, ubuntu, file-synchronization, self-hosted

I have two Ubuntu **servers** (ie. no GUI) that I need to synchronize files across a WAN connection, on an ongoing basis. So far, I've tried BitTorrent Sync and Syncthing, but they are painfully slow. Using rsync, I'm able to synchronize files at over 12 MBps (which is about 90% of my available bandwidth), but using either of the above named tools, I may get a measly 1-3 MBps.

Recently I discovered [websync](http://furier.github.io/websync/), which is a web-based frontend for rsync, which was promising but is very painful to set up and ultimately too challenging for me. I could not get it to work properly.

Are there any file synchronization tools that have a web-based GUI and offer the speed that SCP or rsync do?

Comment: Have you tried a [Google search on "rsync gui linux"](https://www.google.en/search?q=rsync+gui+linux)? What's wrong with the results? ;) Mentioning Ubuntu, our sister-site has something for you: [Is there any GUI application for command rsync?](http://askubuntu.com/q/514963/68291) So while waiting for answers here, you might wish to check those – and then possibly [answer your own question](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) ;)

Comment: There are plenty of results that are applicable to Ubuntu *Desktop* but none that I see that have a web GUI that would be appropriate for Ubuntu *Server*. Same goes for all the answers in the question you linked to. That's why I specified web GUI in the question.

Comment: Ah – got it, thanks. Ubuntu in the start, ubuntu+debian tags, rsync – somehow I missed the "web-based GUI", sorry. Need new glasses ;)

Comment: I need new glasses too. The ones I have don't hold enough beer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

May I recommend Seafile? I have personal experience with setting up & maintaining this application and it's really easy to use. It's open source and is compatible with Ubuntu servers. It seemed pretty fast to me; however, I have never used Rsync (because I've never had to) so I don't know if it's the same speed - it may be faster. It has an awesome web interface and you should be able to get this up and running in no time.

## [Seafile](https://www.seafile.com/) (free - community edition)

> Seafile is a file hosting software system. Files are stored on a central server and can by synchronized with personal computers and mobile devices via the Seafile client. Files can also be accessed via the server's web interface. Seafile's functionality is similar to other popular services such as Dropbox and Google Drive, with the primary difference being that Seafile is free and open-source, enabling users to host their own Seafile servers without artificially imposed limits on
>   storage space or client connections.
>
> [image: Seafile Screenshot]